# Dependency injection, how to inject "other" object?

Tags: php, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I always hear that it is hardcoded:

```
final class Dependency {}

class A
{
    private Dependency $dependency;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dependency = new Dependency();
    }
}
```

ok, let's use dependency injection:

```
class A
{
    private Dependency $dependency;

    public function __construct(Dependency $dependency)
    {
        $this->dependency = $dependency;
    }
}
```

what does it make it better? I cant pass anything other than `Dependency`!

Comment: Imagine that dependency having its own dependencies. And then those dependencies have their own... do you really want that whole mess hardcoded inside the constructor of one specific class? Do you want to repeat it once another class has the same dependency? Or would you rather have one central point (service container) in charge of this instantiation, passing these dependencies into constructors?

Comment: The latter one gives you the privilege of upcasting to a more generic type. For example, `Parent p = new Child();` kind of advantage.

Comment: Or hinting an interface, allowing you to pass whichever concrete implementation you need in a given situation/environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common design is that the dependency is a polymorphic object, that is, a base class or interface. In that case, Dependency Injection enables you to supply any subtype, including Test Doubles.

But even [Concrete Dependencies](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/08/31/ConcreteDependencies) come with some advantages. As the comments suggest, a dependency may be hiding its own big object graph. Additionally, Constructor Injection enables several classes to share a single instance, which you can inject into all objects that need it.